# How to subset or remove rows in facet_wrap (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, facet-wrap

I have a long formatted data-frame where I plotted histograms for each person's data using `facet_wrap()`. But I would like to remove a histogram for a person numbered 106. How can I do this in `facet_wrap()` function without needing to go back and subset my data-frame in `ggplot()` function.

Here's my code:

```
h1 <- ggplot(gnT.Data, aes(rt)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.., fill = ..count..), bins = 100) +
  geom_density(color="red") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low= "#007BFF", high = "#89EBFF")
h2 <- h1 + xlab("Response time (milli seconds)") + 
  ggtitle("Histogram of Response Time") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
h3 <- h2 + facet_wrap(~subnum, scales = "free_y")
plot(h3)
```

Output:
[image: Histogram of Response Time]

Comment: you could run `h3  %+% dplyr::filter(gnT.Data, subnum != 106)`

Comment: Would be easier to answer if your questions was reproducible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963367

Comment: Curious why not subset at ggplot(): `h1 <- ggplot(subset(gnT.Data, pNum != 106),...`?